# Convert utc to GMT-offset using dayjs

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I am trying to convert UTC time received from an API call to a given GMT offset time using dayjs, but the timezone plugin does not seem to accept the GMT offset. Is there a way to convert UTC to the given offset time?

```
const utcTime = '2019-03-06T09:11:55Z' //received from API call
const gmtOffset = 'GMT-05:00'          //change based on condition

const result = dayjs.utc(utcTime).tz(gmtOffset); // error invalid timezone specified
```

We can achieve this using the Angular DatePipe, as shown below:

```
const result = datePipe.transform('2019-03-06T09:11:55Z', 'medium', 'GMT-05:00')
```

can we do same in dayjs also?